# TimeMachine over network without TimeCapsule

Tags: time-machine

Are there any good/easy solutions for using TimeMachine over the network? I am currently unplugging the backup drive from the desktop to backup laptops but would like to do this wirelessly instead if possible.

Comment: It seems you don't [TimeCapsule](http://www.apple.com/timecapsule/)... But just wanted to put it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to share the backup drive with AFP (setup under Sharing in System Preferences).

On your laptop you'll need to go into Terminal and type

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

This will allow your laptop to see the backup drive as a supported Time Machine compatible network drive.   Select this drive in Time Machine preferences and you should be good to go.

Comment: very related: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/backup-mac-homemade-time-capsule/